# File Transfer in a peer to peer network- java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, p2p

I am doing a class project on peer to peer network. Here is a basic overview of the project and what i have done so far:

Overview of the project:

1. There is one central server and it keeps track of all the peers.
2. Role of the central server is simple, it assigns a peer whenever a ***new peer*** joins a network.
3. Once the network is formed, Peers can transfer files.

What have I done so far?

I have used java as the programming language and implemented the following:

1. Written the code for the central server and peers. When a peer joins a network, the central keeps track of the peer that wants to join the network ( by adding it to a local data structure ) and randomly sends another peer's information to the requesting peer ( I am sending the hostname and port number of the an already existing peer ). By doing this, i am constructing the network.

Where i need help?

1. I am really not able to figure out a best logic to transfer a file from one peer to another peer. To me more precise, let's see an example:

Say we have the network as follows:

Node A ----> Node B -----> Node C
                           ( abc.txt )

-----> indicates that the Nodes are virtually connected.

Suppose if Node A requests for a File by name abc.txt, how should the file be downloaded? Node A does not have the information about Node C.  Could anybody tell me the simplest way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your statments looks like contradictory..

"I am sending the hostname and port number of the an already existing peer ".. "Node A does not have the information about Node C."

There can be 2 ways to implement this. According to access.
If Node A can access Node C with its ip and port. - You can create a socket connection to Node C and Copy the file from Node C to Node A.

If the Node C is not visible for Node A - The file may have to uploaded to the Server first and then downloaded from the server to Node A.

Answer (score 0):

Dear for this you have to use the proxy server which will be the central server containing the information of all peers so first connect to the proxy server and through that connect to the desired peer and send the file. For this you will have to send some additional information to the central server on the basis of that central server forward the data. I developed the program like this some times ago.

I have developed one peer for text files, one peer for audio files, one peer for video files and one peer for image files and one Central server (proxy server ) containing the information of all peers. i was sending file to the central server and it was deciding to forward the file the related peer on the basis of file extension.